# Worms in Hinklehatz peppers

Tags: pests, peppers, chili, worms

I cut open some hinklehatz peppers from my garden today to dry them out and to my (unfortunate) surprise, I found some worms living happily inside a few of them!  I stupidly reacted in a disgusted way and got rid of them before I took any pictures, but could someone who has grown these peppers help identify them?  They were tiny, only a few centimeters long and white.  Almost the same color as the seeds.  I actually thought they WERE seeds at first until they started moving.

The peppers themselves also reeked, I'm guessing from the worms causing them to rot.  I noticed two of them had a tiny pin sized hole or two, possibly an entry point. I also cut open some thai peppers which did *not* have any worms if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  They were pepper maggots.